# Apache Redirect and Rewrite

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

In my `.htaccess` file I know how to rewrite a friendly URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /index.php?index=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So, `www.example.com/doit` → `www.example.com/index.php?doit` where `index.php` will handle the rest.

However, I want to handle trailing slashes as well. I can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?index=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which does work, but the URL keeps the trailing slash. I also suspect that the page thinks it’s in the wrong directory.

What I would like to do is catch the trailing slash first and redirect it to a non-slashed version:

`www.example.com/doit/` → `www.example.com/doit` → `www.example.com/index.php?doit`

Presumably then the URL will be fixed, and the rewrite will act as normal.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible adding a `RewriteCond`, maybe there is a shortest way, but i've tested and it's working.

I hope I have answered your question and helped you

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /index.php?index=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /index.php?index=$1 [L,QSA]
```

[image: Testing www.example.com/doit/]

[image: Testing www.example.com/doit]

done with [.htaccess tester](https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can’t get it working. If I try your solution, I get a 500 Internal Server error. The .htaccess Tester, as you note, says it’s OK.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: I was just checking. I get this: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`. I think this may be generating a loop.

Comment: I don't think adding another `RewriteCond` before the last `RewriteRule` solves the problem. A solution is to use an anti-loop rewrite rule, but is used with a lot of rules. In this case there are only 2.

Comment: Are you using `RewriteBase /` before `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: No, `RewriteBase /` is after `RewriteEngine On`.